# no default vpc for this user with .net SDK

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am trying to build a simple web form to spin up EC2 instances.  But I get an error when the describesecuritygroup response gets attached to the ec2client object. "No default VPC for this user"
Any Ideas, snippet of the code:

```
    protected void Button_Build_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ec2client = new AmazonEC2Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest1);


        DescribeVpcsRequest foo1 = new DescribeVpcsRequest()
        {
            VpcIds = new List<string> { "vpc-XXXXXX" }
        };

        DescribeVpcsResponse foo2 = ec2client.DescribeVpcs(foo1);
        ec2client.DescribeVpcs(foo1);            
        var secGroupRequest = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest()


        {
            GroupNames = new List<String> { securitygroup }

        };


        DescribeSecurityGroupsResponse secGroupResponse = ec2client.DescribeSecurityGroups(secGroupRequest);

       SecurityGroup secGroup = secGroupResponse.SecurityGroups[0]; 



       var runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
       {
           ImageId = ami,
           InstanceType = size,
           MinCount = 1,
           MaxCount = 1,
           KeyName = keypair,
           SubnetId = subnetid



       };
       runInstancesRequest.SecurityGroups.Add(securitygroup);
       runInstancesRequest.SubnetId = subnetid;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the example code from AWS documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/run-instance.html

In particular, you need to create a InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification object and add it to the RunInstancesRequest.

(1) Create the object...

```
List<string> groups = new List<string>() { secGroup.GroupId };
var eni = new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification()
{
    DeviceIndex = 0,
    SubnetId = subnetID,
    Groups = groups,
    AssociatePublicIpAddress = true
};
List<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification> enis = new List<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification>() {eni};
```

(2) Add it to the request...

```
   var runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
   {
       ImageId = ami,
       InstanceType = size,
       MinCount = 1,
       MaxCount = 1,
       KeyName = keypair,
       SubnetId = subnetid,

       //***created above***
       NetworkInterfaces = enis

   };
```